# How to Change UIScrollView Sensitivity?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have this `UIScrollView` with `UIView`s in it. Inside the `UIView` there is a `UIImageView` which can be dragged in and out of the `UIScrollView`. The problem is when I tried to drag the `UIImageView` out of the `UIScrollView` within 150ms swiping speed, the `UIScrollView` becomes active and makes the `UIImageView` impossible to drag out (Swiping diagonally/horizontally).

What I know is, `UIScrollView` starts a timer during the first touch event and when the touch ended (within 150ms of touch duration), the scroll view will start to scroll. Is there a possible way to change that 150ms touch duration? Or can I disable the touch event when the user swipes diagonally?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't want the UIScrollView to be active when the user swipes diagonally. When the user swipes vertically, it works fine, the user can drag out the item. If swipes horizontally, the UIScrollView becomes active hence the user can't drag the item out.